# Ferry time from Manado

Tags: tickets, ferries

At what time does the ferry to Bunaken Island leave from Manado Sulawesi? I have heard that it may depend on the tide but that must vary. Does anyone know the cost of private transfer by speed boat and whether they too are dependent on tides

Comment: Where are you staying on Bunaken?  There is no "there there": outside the village, most resorts are reachable only by boat and will arrange transfers as part of staying there.

Answer (score 1):

On getting there, [WikiTravel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Bunaken) reports that Bunaken is about 45 to 60 minutes by boat from Manado.

> Most resorts will arrange transfers from the airport for their guests.
>
> Alternatively, a public boat leaves daily except Sundays at 2-3 PM from the canal on the north side of Manado market. The cost is Rp 50,000 one way for tourists (May 2015) and Rp 10,000 for locals. It returns to Manado from the jetty in Bunaken village around 8-8:30 AM every morning except on Sundays.
>
> You also can charter a private boat to bunaken in the Manado harbor (behind the Celebes Hotel).